# Asp mvc view on specific url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have asp mvc site `www.mysite.com`. I want to create controller with method, that returns view on specific url - `register.mysite.com`. I want to create hidden section of mysite for admins to add new data into site DB. How i can do id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really 'hide' sections of your site, other than not providing a link to it.

Main points

1. protect the section with `[Authorize(role="Admins")]`
2. Somewhere in one of your Views, provide a conditional Link to it.

Point 1) is the real security.

Point 2) would best be done in a Child Action that creates a Model for your menu. Second choice is something like this:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admins")) 
{
   @Html.ActionLink(...)
}
```

Comment: mysite is only shown information from db, users can't register and don't have any account. But admins may login on site and add new data to db.

Comment: Account was just an example, put constraints on all your editing Controllers. For the subdomain, see the linked duplicate. But note that you can always create a separate App for the subdomain.